# specify charset of page loaded in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, browser, utf-8, character-encoding

I was wondering, is it possible to supply a custom charset for a loaded iframe?
E.g if i have a page named `www.example.com` with source code:

```
<meta charset=utf-7>
<html>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have a site named, `www.example2.com`, what i want to do is load `www.example.com` in an `iframe` and set the charset of the loaded `iframe` page to `utf-8`, is this possible? if so how?
Thanks.

Comment: Each page should specify its own charset.

Comment: Are you seriously using UTF-7?

Comment: user2980015: @acfrancis actually did help; That's the answer. The page you load in your iframe should specify its own charset. And... don't be rude.

Answer (score 7):

The page inside the iframe is completely independent of the "outer" page and it can have whatever charset you want. In other words, each page should specify its own charset (and make sure it's actually encoded in that charset).

By the way, your sample code is incorrect. The charset should be declared like this (assuming HTML 5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-7">
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can declare the charset via a HTTP header like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-7
```

More details at http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

It's usually harder to configure the web server to output the correct header for each individual file which is why the `meta` tag is more common.

Comment: It's not totally independent. I'm facing the same problem using Google Chrome. The parent page is UTF-8 but the iframe page is iso-1159. If I open iframe page alone, it works, if I call her inside this parent page, It get's messed up.